# Getting an error while wrapping an element inside a class name in CSS

Tags: html, css, dom

I get errors while writing css like so:

```
.text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;

    a, a:visited {
        font-size: 36px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;  
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

can't I be doing something like a, a:visited inside .text?
My apologies for the trivial question. It has been a while since I used CSS. Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write it like this :

```
.text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.text a, .text a:visited {
        font-size: 36px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;  
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
    }
```

Or you can use Sass and your code will be correct

Comment: Finally someone to mention SASS 

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing vanilla CSS you have to do it like this:

```
.text {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.text a, .text a:visited {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;  
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the class `text` is the parent of the tag `a`, then you need to write in this format:

```
.text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.text a, .text a:visited {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```

if you want to apply the rules for all `a` tags on your page, then the van needs to write the rules in this format:

```
.text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

a, a:visited {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```